# MySQL: Not using index for ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I've been trying and googling everything and still can't figure out what's going on.

I have a big table (100M+rows). Among others it has 3 columns: user_id, date, type.
It has an index `idx(user_id, type, date)`.

When I `EXPLAIN` this query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table 
   WHERE user_id = 12345 
     AND type = 'X' 
ORDER BY date DESC 
   LIMIT 5
```

EXPLAIN shows that MySQL examined 110K rows. which is roughly row many rows this user_id has.

#### My question is:

Why the same index is not used for `ORDER_BY LIMIT 5`? It knows which rows belong to the user_id, date is part of the same index, so why not just take last 5 rows in that index?

P.S. I tried index by (user_id, date, type) - same results; i tried removing DESC - same results.

This is the `EXPLAIN` plan:

```
  id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
  table: s
  type: ref
  possible_keys: dateIdx,userTypeDateIdx
  key: userTypeDateIdx
  key_len: 5
  ref: const,const
  rows: 110118
  Extra: Using where
```

I also tried adding `FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY` hint, but i still get `rows: 110118`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a composite index on the 3 columns or an index for each separate column.

Comment: Can you post the full explain output and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`? That would be very helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: The query execution plan is just showing an estimate of the number of rows MySQL believe it needs to scan. This is just an estimate. For actual number, use the slow query log. You may also like to tell us the time taken for the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ANALYZE TABLE  after creating the index?

Mysql will not use the index until the table is analyzed.  The best index to use is the one you created with (user_id, type, date)

Comment: I analyzed the table, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The date in the index is in ascending order, and you are asking for the most recent five rows in descending order by date; it can't use the index for that.  If you changed the index to `user_id, type, date desc` it would be able to use the index to get the most recent five rows.

Comment: i thought about that, but if i do the same query without DESC, it still shows 100K rows in EXPLAIN plan.