# How to avoid a filesort on a mysql composite index for a prefix query with an order by statement?

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, query-optimization, composite-index

I have a 1 GB mysql table with three colums (german bigrams):

```
create table sortedindex (source varchar(60),target varchar(60),score float)
engine=myisam character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
```

I also created a composite index:

```
create index sortedstd_ix on sortedindex (source(60), target(60), score);
```

additionally I compressed the table and made it read only and sorted the index using:

```
myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq sortedindex
myisampack sortedindex
myisamchk -rq sortedindex --sort_buffer=3G --sort-index --sort-records=1
```

now I ask queries with the following structure:

- fix a source
- specify a prefix for the target
- retrieve top k rows by the score

like the following:

```
select * from sortedindex where source like "ein" and target like "interess%" order by score desc limit 5;
```

mysql explain tells me that is still uses a filesort!

```
mysql> explain select * from sortedindex where source like "ein" and target like "interess%" order by score desc limit 5;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sortedindex | range | sortedstd_ix  | sortedstd_ix | 366     | NULL |   17 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`
```

I understand that if I change the query to:

```
explain select * from sortedindex where source like "ein" and target like "interess%" order by source, target, score desc limit 5;
```

there will be no file sort but WRONG there is a filesort involved.

```
mysql> explain select * from sortedindex where source like "ein" and target like "interess%" order by source, target, score desc limit 5;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sortedindex | range | sortedstd_ix  | sortedstd_ix | 366     | NULL |   17 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602578/mysql-not-using-index-for-order-by) i realize the desc keyword is the problem. so we check without:

```
mysql> explain select * from sortedindex where source like "ein" and target like "interess%" order by source, target, score limit 5;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sortedindex | range | sortedstd_ix  | sortedstd_ix | 366     | NULL |   17 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

perfect that worked.

**BUT I want a descending sorting on the score and not the target.** Creating the index in this way

```
create index sortedstd_ix on sortedindex (source(60), score desc, target(60));
```

is not an option since the target filter will yield for a file sort then or if not the result list of elements that need to be traversed can be really long if the prefix is long and source is a common word.

I somehow have the feeling there is no obvious solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.  There is no obvious solution to this.  Sorting is needed because you are asking for multiple values of target (like "interess%").  Hence, the index will not give you rows that are sorted on score.

Comment: If you aren't providing a solution I have to post a comment to the question, not an answer

Comment: this answer is absolutly correct and provides the answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
select * from sortedindex 
where source like "ein" and target like "interess%" 
order by score desc, source, target limit 5;
```

Comment: explain says it is still using file sort which i actually expected when I read your answer. the order of sorted fields must respect the order of index creation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html