# Performance of selecting articles from multiple categories

Tags: mysql

### Table

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
ALTER TABLE `articles`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`,`created`); ``

My testing:

### query1

`` SELECT sql_no_cache * FROM `articles`  WHERE category_id=1 order by created limit 0,15 ``
Average time: 0.0003

Explain

`id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  articles    ref     category_id     category_id     4   const   1029    Using where`

### query2

`` SELECT sql_no_cache * FROM `articles`  WHERE category_id=1 order by updated limit 0,15 ``
Average time: 0.0019

explain

`id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  articles    ref     category_id     category_id     4   const   1029    Using where; Using filesort`

### query3

`` SELECT sql_no_cache * FROM `articles`  WHERE category_id in (1,2,3) order by created limit 0,15 ``
Average time: 0.0018

explain

`id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  articles    range   category_id     category_id     4   NULL    1105    Using where; Using filesort`

### query4

`` SELECT sql_no_cache * FROM `articles`  WHERE category_id in (1,2,3) order by updated limit 0,15 ``
Average time: 0.0018

explain

`id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  articles    range   category_id     category_id     4   NULL    1105    Using where; Using filesort`

My final need is **query3**.

But from the testing I think only **query1** is using index, because the execute time is much lower than the others.

### Question:

1. There is index on **created**, no index on **updated**, why **query3** and **query4** got save execute time?
2. How can I make the **query3** to use index, or how can improve performance of the **Query3**?

Comment: @Yossi category id could be any. Usage case is: a user subscribed several categories, and system display articles according the categories he subscribed.

Comment: Can you please post the EXPLAIN? You assume the index isn't being used, but that may not be the case. Response times vary based on a lot of other, unrelated factors...

Comment: Do you have indexes on _created_ , _category_id_ , or a covering index on both (and if so in which order)?

Comment: @NevilleK I tested 100 times to get the average execute time, and also add "sql_no_cache". EXPLAIN added.

Comment: @Kickstart I have updated question and added the full table structure.

Comment: How many categories do you have? If you have 3 categories then the index on category will not narrow things down at all, and having category id before the date won't allow the index to help with ordering the results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170579/how-to-avoid-a-filesort-on-a-mysql-composite-index-for-a-prefix-query-with-an-or and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152379/should-we-include-sort-column-primary-key-on-composite-index-mysql look like they address the same issue.

Comment: @Kickstart in my testing there are hundreds of categories. In production there will be thousands of categories, and a general query select from only a few categories(maybe 5~50). That is why I put category id before date.

Comment: The main difference is that it is us _Using where; Using filesort_ . Using filesort is something to usually be avoided. Your query is using the index on category_id, but can't use it to sort the results (as the returned results are not in the order of the index). If you only expect to return a tiny number of rows the time taken to sort the returned rows should be fairly irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [MySQL document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html), MySQL cannot use an index for sorting if "The query uses ORDER BY on nonconsecutive parts of an index". And that would be the case with an "in" clause.

If your ID column is an auto-incrementing integer, and created refers to the date the record was created, you may be able to order by ID instead. This will achieve what I believe you're trying to do, but it is, of course, a bit of a hack...

Comment: Understood. But as I said, there will be large number of categories, means that, the latest 10,000 articles may only contain less than 10 rows of what were selected.That is my concern of "order by ID". One of my ideas is to get 10 IDs of recent updated categories, and make 10 "order by created" queries for each, and combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

are you use "created" is a table keyword you don't use as a field name.
but
select title from articles where category_id in(1,3,7,12,234,333,456) order by `created` DESC limit 0,20
or
select art.title from articles as art where art.category_id in(1,3,7,12,234,333,456) order by `art.created` DESC limit 0,20

try this is work

Comment: I have tried but result is the same. I have updated my question to make it more clearly, could you take a look again?